# How to create a custom function for Dynamic Data Masking

Tags: t-sql, sql-function, nested-function, data-masking, dynamic-data-masking

I'm testing Dynamic Data Masking and I discovered that SQL Server propose [only 4 functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver15) out of the box:

| Function | Examples |
| --- | --- |
| Default | Example of alter syntax: ALTER COLUMN Gender ADD MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') |
| Email | Example of alter syntax: ALTER COLUMN Email ADD MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'email()') |
| Random | Example of alter syntax: ALTER COLUMN [Month] ADD MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'random(1, 12)') |
| Custom String | Example of alter syntax: ALTER COLUMN [Phone Number] ADD MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(1,"XXXXXXX",0)') |

I would like to use the last option, `Custom String`, because I need to:

- Keep 3 prefix number
- Shuffle 3 numbers in the middle
- Keep 3 last numbers

So this phone number `123-456-789` will become `123-039-789`

My first approach is to nest two functions together this way:

```
ALTER TABLE [Person].[PersonPhone]
ALTER COLUMN [PhoneNumber] NVARCHAR(25) MASKED
    WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(4,"' + (FUNCTION = 'random(100,999)') + '",4)');
```

How Can I execute a function inside a function?

Or is there any other option to create a custom `MASK`?

Comment: Your question is elaborate. In my experience, this brings an absence of answers. I recommend you posting on database administrators stack exchange instead, or even the msdn forums.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to combine two data masking functions in SQL Server (2016 or 2019).

I think you want to shuffle (instead of mask) the middle portion because you want the phone numbers to look like they have not been masked, but I don't think this is a good idea. It's better to mask them with X-s, so it is obvious what has been masked. If you have a validation rule somewhere else that says there can be no letters in the phone number, you can mask the middle-portion with 0-s, by using `MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(4,"000",4)')`.

The alternative would be not to use Dynamic Data Masking, but a custom view (or a computed column), where you can call any T-SQL function, for example:

```
LEFT(PhoneNumber,4)+REPLACE(STR(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%1000,3),' ','0')+RIGHT(PhoneNumber,4)
```